# Is there an easy way to see if a user is new or returning user in microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

In Actions on Google - Dialogflow I can write `app.getLastSeen()` to see if the user is interacting with my bot for the first time or is a returning user. Is there a simple way to handle this with Microsoft Bot Framework (C#) or do I have to implement this functionality myself?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that I should implement it myself, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state.

> State data can be used for many purposes, such as determining where the prior conversation left off or simply greeting a returning user by name.